# Calling overridden methods from a vector of superclass pointers

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overriding, stdvector

I am currently writing a small game in OpenGL using C++. Coming from a non-C++ background, I have a simple question about overriding methods and how to call them using a pointer of a superclass type.

This is the case: I have a class `Polygon` containing the method `void draw()`. This class has two children called `Rectangle` and `Circle`, which both override the drawing method, as I am using different OpenGL calls depending on the type of polygon being drawn.

Now consider this: I wish to store all polygons (including both rectangles and circles) in an `std::vector<Polygon*>`. This is perfectly fine. However, iterating through the vector and calling `draw` automatically resorts to the superclass' version of the method.

How can I make a vector of type superclass-pointer, store pointers to subclass objects in it, and call overridden functions depending on the actual type of the object being used?

Comment: You need to declare the method as `virtual` to leverage polymorphism. This is covered in any introductory C++ material on the subject of classes.

Comment: Also, if you are using C++11 or later, get in the habit of marking overridden methods as `override` (ie `void draw() override`). If the base class method is not `virtual`, the compile will fail. That is not the case when `override` is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing polymorphism (or a lack thereof in your current implementation).

To make your `draw` function polymorphic, you must declare it `virtual`. See below for an example:

```
class Polygon {
public:
    virtual ~Polygon() {}
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

class Rectangle : public Polygon
{
public:
    void draw() override { std::cout << "Rectangle::draw()\n"; }
};

class Circle : public Polygon
{
public:
    void draw() override { std::cout << "Circle::draw()\n"; }
};
```

Note three extra things in the above:

1. I also declared the destructor virtual. This allows for proper destruction of an object through its base class pointer.
2. I declared the base `draw` method as pure-virtual (the `= 0` part). This means the `Polygon` class is abstract and cannot itself be instantiated. You may not want that, but to me it seems there's no use for a draw method on a base class anyway. Define one if you want. Up to you.
3. The `override` specifier is optional, but recommended (language feature introduced by C++11). It instructs the compiler that you're intentionally overriding a virtual method, and so if no such method exists to be overridden then it will generate a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the function as virtual in the base class and the override it in the subclasses. For example

```
    #include <vector>
#include <iostream>
struct A{
    virtual void p(){std::cout<<"A ";}
    A(){}
    virtual ~A() {};
};
struct B: public A{
    void p()override{std::cout<<"B ";}
    B(): A(){}
};
struct C: public A{
    void p()override{std::cout<<"C ";}
    C() : A(){}
};
int main()
{
    A* a=new A();
    B* b=new B();
    C* c=new C();
    std::vector<A*> v={a,b,c};
    for(auto i : v)
    i->p();
    std::cout<<"\n";
    delete a;
    delete b;
    delete c;
    return 0;
}
```

prints "A B C".